# Why aren't the values of selected/checked attributes of child select's and input's not retained when copying HTML from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Using jQuery, when I set the HTML of one element as the HTML of another element, the checked attribute of checkbox inputs and the selected attribute of select inputs are not copied. Why is this? For example, let's say a div of class "old" contains several child checkbox inputs, all of which are checked. Now I want to set the inner HTML of another div of class "new" as the inner HTML of div of class "old", like this:

$(".new").html($(".old").html());

All those checkboxes that should be checked are in fact not checked. Why?

Comment: u may look into [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWK9S/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the current state of the element is stored in its DOM properties, not its HTML attributes. When assigning raw HTML, you're only copying the attributes.

If you want to duplicate the element with its current state, use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead:

```
$(".new").replaceWith($(".old").clone());
```

Or, shorter and slightly faster:

```
$(".old").clone().replaceAll(".new");
```

Comment: This solves most of the issues in that it copies over checked attributes of checkboxes, but it does not seem to apply the selected values to select inputs

Comment: I found out why - it's a bug with jQuery that they refuse to fix because of performance: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1294. I found a workaround.